# Remesh parts of mesh

Tags: remesh

Hello wonderful people,

I made a mistake while retopologizing and would love to remesh parts of the model.

As far as I understand, the purple parts on my model have a significantly lower face count, hence I'd love to remesh only those parts to have a one colored model.

Any tips?

[image: remesh parts]

Comment: I would try the following.  In EDIT mode select the purple vertices (assigned by material or vertex group?), Menu >> Mesh >> Separate >> Selection.  You now have 2 (character) objects instead of 1.  Go to object mode, select the purple object, Remesh modifier, Apply the modifier, then select both objects and Join (Ctl-J).

Comment: So tbh, I have no clue why the object has 2 colors. When i go to edit mode, i cant see the purple parts anymore - those are only visible in sculpt mode. And if I just go to edit mode and select the lower part of mz model and then seperate - weird trees start gorwing out of my model :D